# Do coordinate charts contain all open sets in a manifold?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

Consider an atlas $\{(U_\alpha, \phi_\alpha)\}$ for a topological manifold $M$. I am trying to get a better feel for these coordinate charts. Suppose we take any open set $U \subset M$. If the atlas is considered to be maximal, does this imply that every open set has a corresponding coordinate map or is the set $\{U_\alpha\}$ of coordinate sets some collection that covers $M$? If it is the latter, is there any name for the case where *every* open set has a coordinate map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M$ is open in $M$, but $M$ is almost never the domain of a chart: if so, it would imply that $M$ is diffeomorphic to some open subset of $\Bbb R^n$.
The large majority of manifolds are not of this form.

You are right when you say that the domains of the charts of an atlas cover $M$: this is part of the definition of an atlas though.

Comment: I see, so the coordinate sets are just covers of $M$, but not necessarily all the open sets of $M$.

Comment: @CBBAM Yes you are right. If an atlas contains all the open sets, then it contains $M$, and in particular, $M$ is (diffeomorphic to) an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Got it, thank you!